# Eigen colwise() equivalent to reduce an n by m by o matrix

Tags: c++, eigen3

I have a matrix such that

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat(5,10,20);
```

I want to reduce this to an `5` by `10` matrix by summing along the last dimension. If it were a 2d matrix, I could use `colwise()` or `rowwise()`. Is there something I can use here? Or do I need to loop through all elements?

Comment: There is no `Eigen::MatrixXd mat(5,10,20)`. You want to use `Eigen::Tensor`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html

Comment: @chtz Thank you -- I had a true blue screen moment apparently...